# YouTube iframe is shown over the `position: sticky` CSS div

Tags: html, css, youtube, css-position

I'm using a navigation bar `div` to stay on top of the screen using the [`position: sticky;`](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/) CSS trick. Here's pseudo-code:

CSS:

```
#hdr_main_menu{
    margin: .1em 0 2em 0;
    padding: 0.9em 0.1em 0.6em 0.1em;
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
#hdr_mm{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
#clr{
    clear: both;
}

#main_content{
    margin: 2em 1em 0 1em;
}
```

and here's HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="hdr_main_menu">
        <nav>
            <div id="hdr_mm">
                <span>menu items</span>
            </div>
            <div id="clr"></div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="main_content">
        <main> page content </main>
    </div>

</body>
```

This works fine except when I have an embedded YouTube `iframe` in the main content:

It's CSS:

```
#yt0{
    max-width: 1024px;
}

.ytp{
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 1em;
    height: 0;
}
```

it's HTML:

```
<div id="yt0">
    <div class="ytp">
    <iframe title="Title" class="ytp" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QjHNHonuCQU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I scroll this YouTube `iframe` up it scrolls over my top navigation bar with its `position: sticky` style.

Any idea how to make it scroll under it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `z-index` on sticky div. Use below CSS

```
#hdr_main_menu{
   z-index: 99;
}
```

Check here: https://codepen.io/rvtech/pen/GRgrMgE

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

z-index may solve the problem.
Try this :

```
.ytp {
    /* 
       your code
       ....
    */

    z-index: 1000;
    position: relative;
}
```